# Passing a tuple to a curried function

Tags: scala

The following tuple:

```
val i = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

needs to be passed as a parameter to a curried function, as follows:

```
f("param") (i)
```

When defining the curried function, what is the correct way to define the type of the parameter which receives the tuple?

```
def f(s:String) (myTuple:???) = {
  val (a, b, c, d, e. f) = myTuple
  // more code
}
```

I want to avoid having the specify the number and type of each elememt in the tuple when defining the parameter type. In other words, I want to avoid this:

```
def f(s:String) (myTuple:(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)) = {
  val (a, b, c, d, e. f) = myTuple
  // more code
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)`. And it has nothing to do with currying.

Comment: and this line `(a, b, c, d, e. f) = myTuple` should be `val (a, b, c, d, e, f) = myTuple`

Comment: I want to avoid having to specify the number and  type each element of the tuple. Is there not a better way? For non curried functions, I understand one can use the 'tupled' keyword.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out - have updated question

Answer (score 4):

```
val i = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

def f(s:String)(myTuple: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)) = {
  val (a, b, c, d, e, f) = myTuple
}

f("param")(i)
```

Currying doesn't change the way you declare function parameters anyway:

```
val i = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

def f(myTuple: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)) = {
  val (a, b, c, d, e, f) = myTuple
}

f(i)
```

Since you have six parameters, I suggest you use a case class to document their meaning:

```
case class Params(p1: Int, p2: Int, someFancyName: Int, otherName: Int, p5: Int, p6: Int)

def f(myTuple: Params) = {
  val Params(a, b, c, d, e, f) = myTuple
}

val i = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

f(Params.tupled(i))
```

your function parameter will be understood more easily from whoever calls it because each parameter has a name in the case class

I see you edited your question: if you want to avoid specifying the number of elements you can use something like the magnet pattern and implement a magnet for each tuple, or you can use macros.

If you use the magnet pattern, you will have to implement a number of different implementations, depending on the number and type of arguments (you can't be generic in your implementation, you have to know what to do with your arguments). This is a short example for tuples up to three items:

```
abstract class TupleMagnet[T](t: T) {
  def apply(): Unit
}

object TupleMagnet {
  implicit def tuple1Magnet[A](t: Tuple1[A]) = new TupleMagnet(t) {
    def apply() =  { println(t._1) }
  }
  implicit def tuple2Magnet[A, B](t: (A, B)) = new TupleMagnet(t) {
    def apply() = t match { case (a, b) =>  println(""+a + b) }

  }
  implicit def tuple3Magnet[A, B, C](t: (A, B, C)) = new TupleMagnet(t) {
    def apply() = t match { case (a, b, c) =>  println(""+a + b + c) }
  }
}


def f[T](magnet: TupleMagnet[T]) = magnet()

val i = (1, 2, 3)
f(i)

val j = (1, 2)
f(j)
```

Another option to be generic in the number/type of parameters could be using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) `HList`s or `Records` and implementing a [Polymorphic function value](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values) or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Giovanni . A case class will work, but it just seems overkill.

Comment: @user1052610  
I added some more options that are even more overkill :D Scala is a statically typed language, types and number of arguments must be known at compile time

Comment: Hhmm. For now, I'll stick to the case class. Thanks!

Comment: @GiovanniCaporaletti i cannot get the TupleMagnet example to work on scala ide . Can you please edit and copy a working example so i can learn from it.

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya the `abstract class TupleMagnet[T](t: T)` was outside the code formatting box. I edited it. It compiles and runs (prints "123\n12"), if it doesn't' it's a scala ide problem. Sorry but I don't use scala ide

Comment: no it was because of the abstract class TupleMagnet[T](t: T) being outside the box. I could not edit your answer. Sorry.